# メソッドの返り値が変な値になる

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

cocos2d-xでiphone用のアプリを開発しているものです。
今回クロスプラットフォームに対応するため、端末の画面の大きさを取得し、**表示する文字サイズと位置を取得**するメソッドを作成しました。
そのメソッドをメインプログラムから呼び出して、return fontsize position;としているのですが
その値がそのままメインに返ってこないのです。

例)
**ヘッダ**

```
public    int serifuSize(int fontsize,int position);
```

**メイン**
main.cpp

```
int fontsize;
int position;

this ->serifu(fontsize,position);
```

**serifメソッド**

```
int MainScene::serifu(int fontsize,int position){

    //ここで画面幅から端末の情報を受け取り、それを元にfontsizeとpositionを設定する処理(省略)

    return fontsize,position;
}
```

としており、serifu内ではきちんとした値が入っているのにもかかわらず、メインの方に処理が戻り、fontsize内の値とpositionの値を確認したところ、-1074098144こんな感じのデタラメな数字が入っています。

引数のあるメソッドの呼び出し方を調べてみたところCC_CALLBACK_2というものがあり、それを使ってみたのですが

this -> CC_CALLBACK_2(MainScene::serifu, this);

Qualified member access refers to a member in namesepace 'std'

というエラーが出ます。

今一度目的だけを書き出すと、

＊int値（引数は２つ）をメソッドで取得
＊取得したその値を呼び出し元のクラスで使いたい

なのですが、上の内容でどのような問題があるでしょうか。

お願いします。

Comment: 実際に使っているコードを提示できませんか？コードが断片的過ぎて提案できません。とりあえず C/C++ では return で２つの値を返却することはできませんよ。

Comment: fuzzballさんの参照渡しを使ったところ、無事に思うように動作いたしました！本当にありがとうございました！

Comment: @アプリ開発超初心者 解決したら緑のチェック付けましょう、って偉い人が言ってました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

その書き方だと、どちらの変数も値は変化しません。試しに初期値を与えてみれば分かります。

```
int fontsize = 12345;
int position = 67890;
this ->serifu(fontsize,position);
```

正しい書き方ですが、とりあえず参照渡しで書いてみます。

```
void MainScene::serifu(int& fontsize, int& position)
{
    /*
        いろいろ求める
    */
    fontsize = (求めたフォントサイズ);
    position = (求めたポジション);
    return;
}
```